# Xcode 7: crash on breakpoint stop

Tags: xcode, swift, crash, swift2, xcode7

I have an extremely annoying problem!
Xcode 7 crashes almost on every breakpoint when it tries to symbolicate.

I have done several things including deleting Xcode and reinstalling it...

I also had the same issue on the previous Xcode 6.X

Any clue? I am wondering if I should reinstall mac OS from scratch...

Comment: This is a question for Apple support.

Comment: I have filled a DTS, they asked me to do a bug report. It has been 5 days. I'll let you know!

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue - Xcode 7 will crash at breakpoints often in DBGLLDBSessionThread. For me it is C++ code that seems to cause the issue. This problem didn't occur in 6.4.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on 7.3 beta (sure, beta, I know…) and i figured that having multiple windows with debug area panes open triggers an immediate crash when reaching a breakpoint. There are also other things that trigger a crash as well, but this at least was one issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the optimization level in the build settings, make sure it is set to None for Debug configuration and make sure your RUN scheme uses Debug configuration.

[image: Target build settings]

Comment: This did not fix it for me. This is the default setting on mine. Any other suggestions?