# Xcode 7.0 Crashing On Breakpoints

Tags: xcode

I am basically unable to program as Xcode 7.0 crashes on any breakpoint. The interesting thing is that it crashes when trying to resolve addresses to symbols. This is not dependent on any particular Xcode project. Even if I create a new Swift project it still happens. I've tried using a new copy of Xcode and clearing the simulator both of which did nothing.

I'm planning on doing an OS reinstall but decided to ask here to know if there's anything left to try.

There are others reporting this issue as well :

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20889

[Xcode 7: crash on breakpoint stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692165/xcode-7-crash-on-breakpoint-stop)

(Solution described here didn't work).

Comment: Upgrade to xcode 7.1

Comment: Yeah I'm downloading it right now. Fingers crossed. :D

Comment: @Munahil : That worked :D

Comment: great!!! Although you did not need to upgrade to El Capitan

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by upgrading to OS X El Capitan and Xcode 7.1 .